# Multitenant with a single site

Tags: multisite

**What are the best practices to create a multitenant enviroment in wordpress?**

I've created an app with wordpress. Now i would like to make it as a multitenant solution.
I've ended up with two options:

- Create a multisite registration and use the wp network solution (each tenant is a site - a lot of dbs / separated content )
- Single site and use authors on queries (tenant content not well separated / single wp db)

The app is the same for everyone, all interfaces, content types, available options are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I learned about Wordpress network solution I went with option two - setting up certain privileges to users to be able to view and edit content only authored by (and for) them. That can be accomplished by using almost any WP plugin that allows you to change permissions per user, and a few functions that will change how and when things like attachments, post/page count, media library appear. It's manageable, but also a bit of a hassle.

Having recently done a similar thing with WP network, I have to say it's an easier and cleaner solution that already handles most of the issues you would come across using single WP installation. Note: Network doesn't require separate databases from you, merely tables under the same database.

That means that you can query content from other sites (blogs) to avoid its repetition.

All in all, I'd say that for this purpose:

**Wordpress Multisite Network > Single WP installation**

Comment: Yes, it was mistyped...: single db, multiple tables.
Thank you!